# How to retrieve name from Edittext for further manipulation?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences, android-softkeyboard

i have almost completed my game and now i wish to do something with the scores and name so i want to have a high score list...

The problem is that i cannot retrieve the name when i m trying to draw the name using alphabet bitmaps what i have preprared!!!

now the problem occurs when i m tryin to use the getSharedpreferences and m not able to copy the name anywhere in the whole project so that when in the activity of showing the high score i can draw it!!!

is there a simple way to do it please suggest!!!!

thank you!!!

Comment: I m getting the name of the player at the start of the game!!!

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: i m getting the name of the player at the start of the game and after it is typed in the edittext and the game begins the name is no longer available to me...and as the game proceeds the activity changes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to store a value which will be available all around your application is, as you said, the SharedPreferences.

To store your name user you can do this:

```
 SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
 editor.putString("username", "your name");
 editor.commit();
```

To retrieve your username you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = mPrefs.getString("username", "");
```

Comment: SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); what does dis code do???

Comment: It returns the interface for accessing and modifying your preference data. For further information read the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: so i hav to put this code wher i have the edit text and later with the second code i can have the dat which was typed in the edittext???

Comment: When you get the name from edittext pass it into prefs instead "your name" pass string in which you are getting the value and fetch in the last activity with the same key i.e. "username"

Comment: can you also tell me how to retrieve all the game play while u pause and resume to the game!!!